# Play sounds with Java on a Mac

Tags: java, macos, audio

Alright, before I post any code, here's my specs:

- Computer: Macbook Air, Early 2014 model
- Java version: Java 8, Update 65 (Java Control Panel says I'm using the recommended version)
- OS Version: OS X El Capitan, 10.11.1

Now that that's out of the way, I use Terminal as a Console window, `java` to run, and `javac` to compile. I have a class in my project dedicated to playing sounds. The complete code for it is below:

```
package javacoffeeadventure.audiomanager;

import java.io.*;
import javax.sound.sampled.*;
import javacoffeeadventure.io.FileIO;
import javacoffeeadventure.commandinterpreter.*;

public class AudioManager {

    public static void playSound(String soundName) {
        try {
            FileIO f = new FileIO();
            AudioInputStream ain = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(f.getURLForResource("sounds/" + soundName));
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ain);
            clip.start();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            javacoffeeadventure.commandinterpreter.Console.sharedConsole().error("Exception while playing sound " + soundName + ": " + ex.getMessage());
        } finally {

        }
    }

}
```

Where...

- `javacoffeeadventure` is the top-level name of the package
- `commandinterpreter.Console` is a way to do stuff quickly with the Console (I had to use the full name because `java.io.Console` already exists)
- `javacoffeeadventure.io.FileIO` is a simple way to handle resources and load/save a file
- I'm playing a `wav` file

Either way, I'm using `javax.sound.sampled.AudioInputStream`, `javax.sound.sampled.AudioSystem`, and `javax.sound.sampled.Clip` to play sounds.

When invoking `clip.start()`, the following error occurs:

```
2015-11-15 21:23:08.195 java[77192:2681680] 21:23:08.195 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
```

This tells me Java uses an obsolete framework, `CarbonComponent.h`, to play sounds, and OS X suggests Java transition to `AudioComponent.h`.

Is there a workaround available so I can play sounds without using deprecated methods and avoiding unnecessary exceptions?

---

### Edit

The Java Sound API **works**, but it outputs this when letting the Jukebox play:

```
015-11-16 09:23:29.489 java[98123:2879394] 09:23:29.489 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
2015-11-16 09:23:40.572 java[98123:2879867] 09:23:40.572 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Pan
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractLine.getControl(AbstractLine.java:150)
    at Juke.setPan(Juke.java:435)
    at Juke.playSound(Juke.java:302)
    at Juke.run(Juke.java:410)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-16 09:23:54.748 java[98123:2879867] 09:23:54.748 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
Unsupported audio file.
2015-11-16 09:24:00.160 java[98123:2879867] 09:24:00.160 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Pan
    at com.sun.media.sound.AbstractLine.getControl(AbstractLine.java:150)
    at Juke.setPan(Juke.java:435)
    at Juke.playSound(Juke.java:302)
    at Juke.run(Juke.java:410)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2015-11-16 09:24:09.542 java[98123:2879867] 09:24:09.542 WARNING:  140: This application, or a library it uses, is using the deprecated Carbon Component Manager for hosting Audio Units. Support for this will be removed in a future release. Also, this makes the host incompatible with version 3 audio units. Please transition to the API's in AudioComponent.h.
```

Comment: *"Is there a workaround available so I can play sounds without using deprecated methods and avoiding unnecessary exceptions?"* - Not at this time, unless you're prepared to write your own native library to do it.  There may be updates in the near future

Comment: Does the [Java Sound API - Java Sound Demo](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) work for you?

Comment: @MadProgrammer it's actually fixed in openal-soft. Worst case would be **./configure && make && sudo make install** :)

Comment: @AlainO'Dea see the edit

Comment: @DDPWNAGE thank you for trying that and reporting back. It definitely seems like a library issue. Kcat released OpenAL-Soft 1.17.0 late last week, but the AudioComponent.h fix didn't make it in: http://kcat.strangesoft.net/openal.html

Comment: You can build from source, but honestly you're better documenting this message as a known issue for now as it will be fixed and it's outside your control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because OpenJDK is binding to openal-soft for this and it currently depends on Carbon.

There is an open issue on OpenJDK:
https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8138754

It has been fixed in the **master** branch of **openal-soft**:
https://github.com/kcat/openal-soft/issues/20

It has not been released as of **openal-soft 1.17.0** which is the latest release available as I write this.

It should be possible to build an install a newer openal-soft to fix this.  It may be already available in Homebrew.

You can build from source, but I recommend basing your code on the [Java Sound API example](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-139508.html) and documenting this message as a known issue for now as **openal-soft** has been fixed and its release is outside your control.

Comment: @DDPWNAGE does this answer your question now?